# Endless rotate of SVG Polygon on mouseover

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation

I want to rotate a polygon on mouseover, but all I am able to do is a single rotate, I think because the angle is sort of static.
also, the polygon should rotate around itself, what it doesn't. My code looks like:

```
<polygon id="stern"
        points="
        350,370.5  
        370.9,460.1 
        460.9,460.1  
        390.7,510.5
        420.3,600.1
        350  ,550
        270.7,600.1
        300.3,510.5
        230.1,460.1
        320.1,460.1"
        style="fill:#FACC2E"
        onmouseover="rotieren()"/>

<use x="365" y="-380" xlink:href="#stern" transform="scale(0.7)"/>
<use x="1060" y="400" xlink:href="#stern" transform="scale(0.4)"/>
<use x="500" y="700" xlink:href="#stern" transform="scale(0.5)"/>
```

I tried many functions, for example to use a variable, but I can't use it in `.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(variable,0,0))`. Right now, I do

```
document.getElementByID("stern").setAttribut("transform","rotate(5,1060,400)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this?

```
var stern = document.getElementByID("stern");
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    stern.setAttribute("transform","rotate("+(++i)+",1060,400)")
},50)
```

Comment: hm, well, i am not able to completly understand this.
When do i "cast" the variable interval?

Comment: It passes a function into window.setInterval, which then gets executed every 50ms and performs the frames in your animation. The variable `interval` is just the ID of the interval, in case you want to later call window.clearInterval to stop animating.

Comment: hm, so i tried calling <polygon id="star" ... onmouseover=window.setInterval() onmouseout=window.clearInterval() />, using the script you wrote, but it doesn't work yet.
sorry that i dont understand it yet. hope you can still help me.

Comment: `setInterval` calls a function you specify at an interval you specify, indefinitely, and passes back an ID. You can then pass that ID into `clearInterval` to stop it. e.g. this will only be called once, after 100ms, because I clear the interval timer the first time it's called `var id = setInterval(function(){ clearInterval(id) },100)`. There's plenty of documentation around setInterval and clearInterval, Google will help if it's not clear.